# Modal box not show after form validation check

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I have a registration form and in this form, I give validation to some input fields `required`. After the validation check, I want to open a modal box `$('#exampleModal').modal('show');` but it's not working

Code:

```
<form class="well form-horizontal"   id="contact_form" autocomplete="off">
<fieldset>
<legend><center><h2><b>Registration Form</b></h2></center></legend><br>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 pd-r control-label">firstname</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 pd-r inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
   <input  name="first_name" id="first_name"  class="form-control tboxs"  type="text" minlength="4" required>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 pd-r control-label">village</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 pd-r inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
     <input name="village" id="village" class="form-control tboxs" type="text" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 pd-r control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4 pd-r"><br>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn-theme-colored btn">SUBMIT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><font color="black"><strong>Verify OTP</strong></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <form method="POST"  id="otp_form" action="">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control tboxs" id="otp_data" name="otp_data" placeholder="Enter OTP" maxlength="4" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="verifyotp" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">Verify</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function(){
   if($('#first_name').val()==''){
      alert('Name can not be left blank and atleast 4 char long');
      return false;
    }
   if($('#village').val() == ''){
      alert('village can not be left blank');
      return false;
   }
   $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
   return true;
});
</script>
```

In the code, validation is working after the validation check modal box not open. I do no know where I am wrong in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is you updated `script` and `html` code

**Issue with HTML code:**

- Button type was `submit` but you are calling `click` event on it
- You didn't assigned `id` to particular button `eg: id='submit'`

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
   if($('#first_name').val() == '' ){
      alert('Name can not be left blank and atleast 4 char long');
      return false;
   }
   if($('#village').val( ) == '') {
      alert('village can not be left blank');
      return false;
   }
   $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
   return true;
   
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <form class="well form-horizontal" id="contact_form" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><center><h2><b>Registration Form</b></h2></center></legend><br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 pd-r control-label">firstname</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4 pd-r inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
       <input  name="first_name" id="first_name"  class="form-control tboxs"  type="text" minlength="4">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 pd-r control-label">village</label> 
        <div class="col-md-4 pd-r inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
         <input name="village" id="village" class="form-control tboxs" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 pd-r control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4 pd-r"><br>
        <button type="button"  id="submit" value="submit" class="btn-theme-colored btn">SUBMIT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><font color="black"><strong>Verify OTP</strong></h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
             <form method="POST"  id="otp_form" action="">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control tboxs" id="otp_data" name="otp_data" placeholder="Enter OTP" maxlength="4" required="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="verifyotp" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">Verify</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```